# What basic operations on a Map are permitted while iterating over it?

Tags: java, iterator

Say I am iterating over a Map in Java... I am unclear about what I can to that Map while in the process of iterating over it. I guess I am mostly confused by this warning in the Javadoc for the Iterator interface remove method:

> [...] The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this method.

I know for sure that I can invoke the remove method without any issues. But while iterating over the Map collection, can I:

1. Change the value associated with a key with the Map class put method (put with an existing key)?
2. Add a new entry with the Map class put method (put with a new key)?
3. Remove an entry with the Map class remove method?

My guess is that I can probably safely do #1 (put to an existing key) but not safely do #2 or #3.

Thanks in advance for any clarification on this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `Iterator.remove()`, and if using an entrySet iterator (of Map.Entry's) you can use `Map.Entry.setValue()`.  Anything else and all bets are off - you should not change the map directly, and some maps will 
not permit either or both of the aforementioned methods.

Specifically, your (1), (2) and (3) are **not** permitted.

You *might* get away with setting an existing key's value through the `Map` object, but the `Set.iterator()` documentation specifically precludes that and it will be implementation specific:

> If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation, or through the setValue operation on a map entry returned by the iterator) the **results of the iteration are undefined**. (emphasis added)

Comment: I confirm that your suggestions are nice. Map.Entry.setValue() works like a charm, Iterator.remove() too.

Comment: For completeness, what about modifying the iterator current value via public mutator? There's no way the Map has visibility into every entry's method calls, right?

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the HashMap class, you'll see a field called 'modCount'.  This is how the map knows when it's been modified during iteration.  Any method that increments modCount when you're iterating will cause it to throw a ConcurrentModificationException.

That said, you CAN put a value into a map if the key already exists, effectively updating the entry with the new value:

```
 Map<String, Object> test = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 test.put("test", 1);

 for(String key : test.keySet())
 {
     test.put(key, 2); // this works!
 }

 System.out.println(test); // will print "test->2"
```

When you ask if you can perform these operations 'safely,' you don't have to worry too much because HashMap is designed to throw that ConcurrentModificationException as soon as it runs into a problem like this.  These operations will fail fast; they won't leave the map in a bad state.

Comment: These methods *try* to fail-fast, but due to memory concurrency issues they *may* not always if the modification is done in another thread. Always program to the API documentation; never violate it because "I tried it and it worked", since it might work only on your (a) JVM, or (b) hardware, or (c) specific configuration but not others.

Answer (score 2):

There is no global answer. The map interface let the choice to the users. Unfortunately, I think that all the implementations in the jdk use the *fail-fast* implementation (here is the definition of fail-fast, as it stated in the [HashMap Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)):

> The iterators returned by all of this
>   class's "collection view methods" are
>   fail-fast: if the map is structurally
>   modified at any time after the
>   iterator is created, in any way except
>   through the iterator's own remove
>   method, the iterator will throw a
>   ConcurrentModificationException. Thus,
>   in the face of concurrent
>   modification, the iterator fails
>   quickly and cleanly, rather than
>   risking arbitrary, non-deterministic
>   behavior at an undetermined time in
>   the future.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want to change the Map while iterating over it, you should use one of the iterator's methods. I have not actually tested to see if #1 will will work, but the others definitely will not.